# Excel: Map a function across a 2-d array, then call a function on the resulting column array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'd like to use a single formula in excel without using VBA or macros to traverse a 2-dimensional array and produce a single value. The formula would do the following:

First, iterate through every row of the data, calling a function (in my case, MAX) on each row. This will return a column of values. Then call a single function (in my case, SUM) on that column of values. This should return a single value.

In programming terminology, if I am given a 2-dimensional array of values in row-major-order, I'd like to map the function MAX across the 2-d array, and then call SUM on the resulting 1-d array.

Is there a way to do this in excel in a single cell formula?

Thanks so much. Please let me know if I can make this question clearer in any way, or if I should be asking this question somewhere else.

Comment: give a screenshot of your data, or share an example worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

Such requirements are normally achieved with array formulas. But there is no universally usable solution for all such requirements. For functions which are usable with SUBTOTAL, this could be achieved like follows:
[image]

```
{=SUM(SUBTOTAL(4,OFFSET($A$2:$E$2,ROW($A$2:$A$6)-ROW($A$2),0)))}
```

This is an array formula. Enter the formula in the cell without curly brackets and press [CTRL]+[SHIFT]+[ENTER] then. The curly brackets then should appear automatically.

How it works:
The part ROW($A$2:$A$6) gets a array of row numbers {2,3,4,5,6}. The -ROW($A$2) subtracts the start row, so the resulting array is {0,1,2,3,4}. The OFFSET part then shifts $A$2:$E$2 by {0,1,2,3,4} rows and results in a array of row vectors {$A$2:$E$2, $A$3:$E$3, ..., $A$6:$E$6}. From those the SUBTOTAL gets the MAX values per row and the SUM sums these MAX values.

Instead of SUM as array formula in this case we can also use SUMPRODUCT. This gets its parameters in array context automatically. So with this it is not necessary to enter the formula as array formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(4,OFFSET($A$2:$E$2,ROW($A$2:$A$6)-ROW($A$2),0)))
```